# Java-8 Stream: get Entry with latest myDate

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of following entities and I will get the one with the highest myDate. Can somaone give me a hint how to do this.
Thanks!

```
 public class MyClass {

    private DateTime myDate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there's no public `DateTime` class in the JDK. Probably you meant `LocalDateTime`. As it's `Comparable`, you can use `Stream.max`. Suppose you have `List<MyClass> myList`. Use:

```
Optional<MyClass> highest = myList.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(c -> c.myDate));
```

[`Stream.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) method returns an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) which is empty when your input list is empty.